Creating multiple fiscal year calendars with overlapping quarters in the system
I am working on a client requirement for creating multiple fiscal year calendars with overlapping quarters in the system.
Example - For first LOB, FY starts from 1/1/2024 and ends in 12/12/2024.
For second LOB, FY starts from 4/1/2024 and ends in 3/31/2025.
Salesforce is not allowing to save the above two calendars( through custom fiscal year feature) since they have overlapping quarters.
It's throwing an error for the same
Has anyone implemented a similar use case? Or has any alternate solution to the use case

Could you please describe your use case. Fiscal years - as you know - are implicit in a number of Salesforce calculations. If two fiscal years applied for the same date, Salesforce wouldn't know what to do.
